# Strategy won't open or close positions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My strategy won't open or close any positions and I'm not sure why. It uses EMA and MACD with a trailing stop loss. It opens when the EMA7 crosses over EMA14 and the MACD signal crosses over the MACD variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
strategy('EMA and MACD with Trailing Stop Loss',
         overlay=true,
         initial_capital=1000,
         process_orders_on_close=true,
         default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
         default_qty_value=30,
         commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,
         commission_value=0.1)

showDate = input(defval=true, title='Show Date Range')
timePeriod = time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2022, 1, 1, 0, 0)
notInTrade = strategy.position_size <= 0

// EMAs 
fastEMA = ta.ema(close, 7)
slowEMA = ta.ema(close, 14)
plot(fastEMA, color = color.blue)
plot(slowEMA, color = color.green)
buyCondition1 = ta.crossover(fastEMA, slowEMA)


// DMI and MACD inputs and calculations
[macd, macd_signal, macd_histogram] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
buyCondition2 = ta.crossover(macd_signal, macd)


// Configure trail stop level with input options
longTrailPerc = input.float(title='Trail Long Loss (%)', minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=3) 
* 0.01
shortTrailPerc = input.float(title='Trail Short Loss (%)', minval=0.0, step=0.1, 
defval=3) * 0.01

// Determine trail stop loss prices
longStopPrice = 0.0
shortStopPrice = 0.0

longStopPrice := if strategy.position_size > 0
    stopValue = close * (1 - longTrailPerc)
    math.max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
else
    0

shortStopPrice := if strategy.position_size < 0
    stopValue = close * (1 + shortTrailPerc)
    math.min(stopValue, shortStopPrice[1])
else
    999999


if (buyCondition1 and buyCondition2 and notInTrade and timePeriod)
    strategy.entry(id="long", direction = strategy.long)

strategy.exit(id="long", stop = longStopPrice, limit = shortStopPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below means both conditions MUST happen at the same candle. Is that the case?

```
buyCondition1 and buyCondition2
```

Maybe do something like this?

```
buyCondition1 = fastEMA > slowEMA

// DMI and MACD inputs and calculations
[macd, macd_signal, macd_histogram] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
buyCondition2 = ta.crossover(macd_signal, macd)
```

Comment: Yes, that is the case. Thank you, this works, but I'm unsure as to why. Aren't 'fastEMA > slowEMA' and 'ta.crossover(fastEMA, slowEMA)' the same?

Comment: Not the same. The pine keeps run your code after the k bar closed in short.
fastEMA > slowEMA -> at the end of every k bar: return true
ta.crossover(fastEMA, slowEMA) -> please read the manual. only return true in that cross k bar, otherwise false